# Make div width go to max-width

Tags: html, css

I have the typical 3 column layout and I need it to be fluid (ish). The specs of the projects are: we need the container to go from 1024px to 1440px max (that's easy). And the center column needs to go from 514 (at 1024) to 626 (at 1440), the sidebars on both sides containing the rest of the space.

I don't see an easy way around this, I've played with max-width and min-width but since the proportions are not the same at the 2 breakpoints, I can't use percentage width to make the columns fill the space on higher resolutions.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <nav id="sidebar-left">Left</nav>
    <section id="page">Center</section>
    <div id="sidebar-right">Right</div>
</div>


#container{
    min-width:1024px;
    max-width: 1440px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#sidebar-left{
    min-width: 230px;
    max-width: 387px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
}
#sidebar-right{
    min-width: 230px;
    max-width: 387px;
    float: right;
    background: blue;
    height: 300px;
}
#page{
    min-width: 514px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    max-width: 626px;
    float: left;
    background: purple;
    height: 300px;
}
```

And I also made a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1y59nuxz/

I'd rather have a css only solution, I'm pretty sure is more or less easy to solve using jquery but I'd want to know if this is approachable with using it.

EDIT: I need this to be compatible with IE9+

Comment: I think you have to use "%"  for columns width

Comment: Read again, the percentage of the columns is not the same between the breakpoints. 626px in a 1440px screen is 43,47% of it, 525px in a 1024px screen is 51,26%. So I can't use that.

Comment: Then maybe you can use some media queries ?

Comment: @ElaineMarley  see this link https://jsfiddle.net/1y59nuxz/1/

Comment: No, that is not right according to the specs I'm provided. If I could ignore the sizes I would have done it that way too Shibin Ragh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. You have several solutions to accomplish this task.

One solution is to change order of elements in your html (if possible):

```html
<div id="container">
  <nav id="sidebar-left">Left</nav>
  <div id="sidebar-right">Right</div>
  <section id="page">
    <div class="page-inner">Center</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

For "#page" use next css code:

```css
#page {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}

.page-inner {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background: purple;
}
```

Example code:

```css
#page {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px;
}

.page-inner {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 20px;
    background: purple;
}

#container{
    min-width:1024px;
    max-width: 1440px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#sidebar-left{
    min-width: 230px;
    max-width: 387px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
}
#sidebar-right{
    min-width: 230px;
    max-width: 387px;
    float: right;
    background: blue;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <nav id="sidebar-left">Left</nav>
    <div id="sidebar-right">Right</div>
    <section id="page">
        <div class="page-inner">Center</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

You can also check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1y59nuxz/5/).

Another solution is to apply flexbox. It's an elegant and easy way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this layout can be achieved using some `table` & `table-cell` css like so:

- basically set the `.container` to `display: table`
- then set all direct children of the `.container` to `display: table-cell`
- now these children will shrink/grow accordingly to their parent, however some tweaks have to be made for the `#page` to stay put at 626px widh and shrink down accordingly
- `max-width/min-width` combo won't work on the `#page` div, however we can specify a fixed width, according to the max-width desired, in this case `626px`, so that this div won't go past `626px` width, but will shrink down if the window is resized
- finally since we're using `display: table-cell` on these children divs, any margin prop. will be ignored, however we can mimic a margin using some border-left & right props. OR add another div inside the `#page` div that will hold the content and have some margin applied to it and the background accordingly.

---

Check out the demos bellow:

- fake margins to the `#page` **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/hr49rg94/3/)**
- OR another div that holds the content for `#page` **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/5yxzhydz/1/)**

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something like that, but it will probably have issues with the content in the sidebars, that will be links and images and stuff. I think I might have to ignore the specs and go for a percentage based layout instead with the same proportions through all the resolutions.

Comment: Well if you can add another divs inside those sidebars, much like I did for the #page on the second example, that will hold the content inside it, it should work pretty well, however if that's out of the option, depending on what youll put inside those sidebars, some issues may appear with having a table cell parent

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avnaveen91/06as25L2/2/)

or else check the code below.

Html

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content__left">left</div>
    <div class="content__right">Right</div>
    <div class="content__middle">Center</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, .container {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:1024px;
    max-width: 1440px;
}
.content__left {
    width: 20%;
    max-width:200px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:300px;
}
.content__middle {
    min-width: 514px;
    background: purple;
    overflow: auto;
    height:300px;
}
.content__right {
    width: 20%;
    max-width:200px;
    float: right;
    background: blue;
    margin-left:20px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: This will be what I will do but it is not a correct answer to my question, since the width of the divs are not always the same percentage of the parent.